# Dropdown created by EasyAdmin Bundle not closing on select

Tags: symfony, google-chrome, easyadmin

I am creating a backend to my Symfony4.2 site using the easyadmin bundle. in the new/edit form created for my entities it creates a dropdown to select from. However, in chrome and firefox these dropdowns are not behaving as expected.  When I click on them it shows the options but it does not close if I select an option or click away from the dropdown menu.  It works okay on Safari and Edge.

Here is the easyadmin.yaml

```
easy_admin:
    #Global Settings
    site_name: 'Physics Quiz SIte'

    design:
        assets:
            favicon: '/build/images/favicon.ba133a8b.ico'
    # this is the default form theme used by backends
        form_theme: '@EasyAdmin/form/bootstrap_4.html.twig'
    # these custom templates are applied to all entities
        brand_color: '#1ABC9C'
        menu:
            - { label: 'Public Homepage', route: 'homepage', icon: 'home' }
            - { entity: 'User', icon: 'user' }
            - { entity: 'QuestionType' }
            - { entity: 'Question' }
            - { entity: 'Quiz' }

    show:
        max_results: 10

    list:
        actions:
            - { name: 'edit', icon: 'pencil'}
            - { name: 'delete', icon: 'trash'}
        # allow deleting multiple items at once ...
        batch_actions: ['delete']

    # List the entity class name you want to manage
    entities:
        Quiz:
            class: App\Entity\Quiz
            form:
                fields:
                -   property: 'quizname'
                    label: 'Quiz Name'
                -   property: 'course'
                    type: 'entity'
                    type_options:
                        expanded: false
                        multiple: false
```

This is the relevant page source that is created:

```
<div class="col-12 ">
 <div class="form-group  field-entity">
  <label class="form-control-label required" for="quiz_course">Course</label>
  <div class="form-widget">
   <select id="quiz_course" name="quiz[course]" data-widget="select2" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Year 10 Physics</option>
    <option value="2">Year 11 Physics</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and here are the scripts that may be relevant.

```
<script src="/bundles/easyadmin/select2/i18n/en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Select2 widget is only enabled for the <select> elements which
    // explicitly ask for it

    function init() {
      $('form select[data-widget="select2"]').select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        language: 'en'
      });
    }

    $(document).on('easyadmin.collection.item-added', init);
    init();
  });
</script>
```

Here is a picture of the rendered dropdown:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug introduced in version 2.1.2.

https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/2715

There was a new release 2.1.3 that fixes the problem.

Comment: Sweet...I'm having this exact issue too :)